# Reply/to address for replies to emails that received no reply

Tags: mail.app

Steps:

- I send an email.
- I wait some days, and I receive no response (the recipient never replies). I now wish to send a follow-up email.
- I locate the first email I sent (either by searching or scrolling, in either my "sent" folder or "all mail", doesn't matter, 
  same outcome).
- I click the reply button or hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>r</kbd> (doesn't matter, same outcome).
- I compose a second message.
- I click send.

Expectation:

- My second email should go to my recipient.

Unexpected outcome:

- My second email is sent to myself instead.

I'm new to Apple macOS Mail app. I'm more familiar with Gmail, but I recently switched to free my email from my web browser. However, I don't understand why anyone would want this behavior, and I'm hoping there's a way to fix it that I've not found.

**UPDATE:**

In troubleshooting after the comments below, it seems this problem occurs *only* for ignored emails sent *before* I switched from Gmail web app to Apple Mail app. I guess that's good news (in that eventually the problem should become irrelevant the longer I use Mail app), but why should this even occur?

Software:

- Mail app version 12.4
- macOS version 10.14.4 (Mojave)

Comment: When you say you click reply, is this on the email in the Sent folder? Because when I do that, it creates a new email to the original recipient. (Same versions of Mail and OS)

Comment: "I receive no response." What type of response are you looking for?  You will not get a response email unless the receiver sends you a reply.

Comment: When I wrote "I receive no response", I mean I sent the email, waited a week, and the recipient never replied. I'm trying to send a follow-up email.

Comment: Whether I locate the message in "Sent" or "All Mail", and whether I reply by clicking the reply button or hitting command-r, makes no difference.

Comment: You could try Reply All. That should generate an email addressed to both you and the original recipient. You can then delete your email address.

Comment: Regarding using reply-all: The point is that I expect reply to send to the other party, and I'd like to know why it doesn't. Reply-all might include additional parties that might not be desired.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the recipient/ To email address if that mention your name then it will come on to your email address.

Comment: I shouldn't have to check the to/cc/bcc fields. The reasonable expectation for reply is to populate "to" with the other party. I'd like to know why this fails.

Comment: The best way to get of this issue is to remove the email account from mail and set it up again. This will resolve the issue.